# Custom Health check with GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-health

Hi I try to use custom health check with GCP LoadBalancer.

I have added `readinessProbe` & `livenessProbe` like this:

```
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /health
        port: dash
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 10
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /health
        port: dash
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 10
```

But when I create my ingress I haven't got my custom health check

[Path LB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwVxq.png)

Comment: Back in the days this was possible. Not sure if it is still supported. If it is, what you have to do is to set up a liveness probe. If the liveness probe goes through, then GCP Load Balancer would adopt that endpoint for the health check of the nodes. Is your liveness probe going through? Do you get 200?

Comment: I had a similar problem and noticed the readinessProbe needs to by defined before creating Ingress resource - it won't pick up later changes. Is it possible this is your case as well?

Comment: I tried to wait 10 minutes before creating the ingress but no effect ..

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/0d15eedbefb931b401ef9fc1d6e1a7d73c08dbc4/pkg/backends/backends.go#L570 "Kubernetes L7 health check generated with readiness probe settings."...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I **FINALIZED** an answer. What I was trying to do was impossible. My GCE Ingress used a backend on port `80` . But in my ReadinessProbe I told him to check on port `8080` and on the `/health` path. **This is impossible!**

The port of the service declared in the Ingress backend must be the same as that declared in the `readinessProbe`. **Only the path can be different**. If we do not respect this pattern, it is `/` that is associated with the Health Check GCP path.

From a network point of view this is logical, the Health Check GCP is "out" of the Kube cluster, if we tell it to route on port `80` but our `ReadinessProbe` is on another port, how it can ensure that even if the port associated with the ReadinessProbe meets port `80` (which is the one on which it must route traffic) also respond.

**In summary, the port of the backend declared in Ingress must have a `readinessProbe` on the same port. The only thing we can customize is the path.**

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused between resources in GCP.

The code you posted is at no moment in relation to a Load balancer resource, as it's a kubernetes health check for pod states. If you want to know if the probes are working, check your pod state, if it's not running describe your pod and look at the logs, should indicate an issue with the probes.

I'm going to guess that you have an ingress resource somewhere in your kubernetes conf wich creates the lb and all the resources around it like the health check (still guessing that the image you posted is in relation to that).

If you are using GKE you should leave the google automated resource conf from k8s config you deployed as it is, cause you may brake some things that google is already maintaining for you.

Comment: When I create an Ingress on GKE with GCE class, LB create backend and health check. The health check is binding on `/`path. 

But let’s take an example, we have an app that on the path `/` makes a redirect ( `302` ) on/dashboard. Since the returned HTTP code is not `200` , our service returns `UNHEALTHY` .

I know it is possible to modify the Endpoint of the healthcheck by hand but I would like to do it automatically and especially as the heathcheck corresponds to my Readiness .

Comment: I may have said something wrong: you can find the same question as yours here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018193/gce-ingress-not-picking-up-health-check-from-readiness-probe?rq=1 but there is no validated answer...

Comment: No problem. I just find a possible answer : 
https://github.com/pusher/oauth2_proxy/issues/86 & https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/issues/27 . But I think GCP Ingress is constraining...